# Java inheritance why does this toString prints BB and not AB, AB?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm executing this and i cant understand why does this executes and prints BB in both lines.

```
class A {
    public String toString(){
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a = new B();
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Because both times it's an object of the class B.

Comment: Why? Because `A a = new B();` , so `a` is really an instance of `B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one class name per object in java. If you want to know the name of super class, you have to use: `getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName()`.

Since both objects are `new B()`, doesn't matter if you are calling `super.toString()` or `toString()`, both will return the name of class `B`, because `getClass()` return always the name of the class that you created by using `new`.

Comment: Yes but why does not call the parent superclass that it's classname is A??

Comment: Its a little circular @SantiagoM super calls A's toString, which calls getClass. Now getClass returns B because the object is of type B.